# R String being trimmed after importing from text file

Tags: r, import, trim

each line in my .txt contains a text, like:

```
FORMAT=2.1
(TYPE=test
[DESCRIPTION="This is a test data set for study purpose only"
]
)
```

However, after I import it into R, some of the characters are not fully imported. The data type is `tbl_df`.

example:
string in .txt:

```
[DESCRIPTION="This is a test data set for study purpose only"
```

I expect the imported string would be:

```
"[DESCRIPTION=\"This is a test data set for study purpose only\""
```

However, this is a string appearing in Rstudio,

```
"[DESCRIPTION=\"This is a test data set for study purpose "
```

Is it because there is a limit for `string` type data? I use `nchar()` and see that all the strings disappear after the 56th character.

Is it possible to keep everything in 1 line? Thank you for your help.

#

Just realize it was my mistake. The text file was unable the import:

Here is the text format and error

```
FORMAT=2.1
(TYPE=Line2
[DESCRIPTION="This is a test data set for study purpose only"
]
)
(TYPE=Line6
[DESCRIPTION="This is a test data set for study purpose only"
]
)
(TYPE=Line10
[DESCRIPTION="This is a test data set for study purpose only"
]
)

> rtest <- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/rtest.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 10 elements
```

Because I use excel import first, so I thought the text file is imported but actually I was watching on the excel dataset. So this would be a different question, Thank you for you guys' help. I am going to delete this post soon after update with you guys.

Comment: If the first code block above is truly representative of how the file looks, then what is returned will depend heavily on the code you use. Can you please include it in your question?

Comment: Can you show the command you are using to import the data? `read.table(text = '[DESCRIPTION="This is a test data set for study purpose only"')` works fine for me, and when I save your sample lines as a file and do `readLines("sample.txt")` it also works just fine.

Comment: ...as does `readr::read_lines('FORMAT=2.1
(TYPE=test
[DESCRIPTION="This is a test data set for study purpose only"
]
)')`

Comment: I use the Import Dataset function from the Rstudio. I have the version 1.1.442
`Test<- read.table("C:/Users/Desktop/Test.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")`